# Struggle to read data with serial port of Rasp3

Tags: pi-3, serial, uart

Sorry if I am asking something very basic, did not find any good post on how to handle this.. I am following a tutorial on how to communicate with my PI 3 using UART. I followed theses steps:

- Delete "console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200" and add" enable_uart=1" in /boot/cmdline.txt
- Delete "T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100" in /etc/inittab
- reboot
- do "sudo stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 115200 cs8 -cstopb -onlcr -echo -echoe -echok -opost"
- plug RX and TX together (for test purpose)

Then i try to write/read data on the the serial port using the command line or/and python but nothing happens.

Could you help me please?

Cheers,